# URL -web scraping with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am  trying to scrape content from LinkedIn using R, but I keep on getting an error when trying to read the HTML content.

This is my code :

```
install.packages("curl")
library("selectr")
library("xml2")
library("rvest")
library("stringr")
library("curl")
url="https://www.linkedin.com/in/hollyhynes/" 
webpage <- read_html(url)
```

The error is:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 999

I tried using the `curl` package :

```
webpage=read_html(curl("https://www.linkedin.com/in/hollyhynes/",handle 
  = new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0")))
```

but it also returned an error:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 999.
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In if (!is.character(x)) x <- structure(as.character(x), names = 
>   names(x)) :
>   closing unused connection 5 (https://www.linkedin.com/in/hollyhynes/)
>   2: In if (!is.character(x)) x <- structure(as.character(x), names = 
>   names(x)) :
>   closing unused connection 4 (https://www.linkedin.com/in/hollyhynes/)
>   3: In if (!is.character(x)) x <- structure(as.character(x), names = 
>   names(x)) :
>   closing unused connection 3 (https://www.linkedin.com/in/hollyhynes/)

would appreciate some help on how can I fix  it 
 thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to login with your browser and copying the session cookie to your curl session

Comment: HTTP error 999 is LinkedIn telling you that it thinks you're a robot and denying your connection. LinkedIn's ToS do not permit scraping. You can try using its API instead, even though it's quite restricted.